# How to count the number of key value pairs in a mongodb document using node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My document looks like the following:

```
{
    "Erow1": "funnnyyyy hahaha",
    "Erow2": "Prefer a public role",
    "Erow3": "Can sometimes be easily distracted",
    "Erow4": "I'm awesome"
}
```

I need to know the number of elements inside the document. For example, here there are 4 key/value pairs.
I'm retrieving the doc on my nodejs server like this

```
    app.get("/editMBTI", function editMBTIFunc(req, res)
{ 
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, client) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        console.log("Connected Successfully to the Database server");
        const db = client.db(dbName);
        //getting the whole collection of MBTI sets
        var cursor= db.collection("mbti_testcontent").find();
        cursor.toArray(function (err, doc) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            console.log(doc[0]);
            // get the count of the key-value pairs present in doc[0] here.    
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation framework to do that:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    { 
        $project: {
            numberOfKeys: {
                $let: { 
                    vars: { array: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } },
                    in: { $add: [{ $size: "$$array" }, -1] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

For each document we're doing a projection which will return _id and a number of keys. Used operators:

- [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) to define temporary variable
- temporary variable `array` contains all the keys and values inside entire document (`$$ROOT` is a special variable representing whole doc), to get those keys and values we're using [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html)
- [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) measures the size of an array (length), we also need to subtract 1 representing _id if you don't want to include it in a result